# delete one specific widget in python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to delete a widget that has the name of a string but I cant find how to do it. This is what I have done so far but I cant get my head around that. I want to be able to select the name of the widget that I want to get deleted. any help would be useful

and this is the code that i have made so far

```
lasthover = "button1"
def dlt():
       for widget in frm.winfo_children():
        if widget == lasthover:
            widget.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the widget name using option `name` when creating the widget and then destroy it using the given name.

Below is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

frm = tk.Frame(root)
frm.pack()

# create buttons with name button1, button2, etc
for i in range(1, 10):
    name = f"button{i}"
    tk.Button(frm, text=name, name=name).pack(side="left")

lasthover = "button1"

def dlt():
    for widget in frm.winfo_children():
        if widget._name == lasthover:
            widget.destroy()

tk.Button(root, text="Destroy Button", command=dlt).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so here is my solution (using classes), this is how I did it in one of my projects (similarly), this also may raise a lot of questions so feel free to ask:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button


root = Tk()
removable_widget_dict = {}


class RemovableWidget(Button):
    def __init__(self, title, parent, key):
        Button.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title = title
        self.key = key

        self.button = Button(self.parent, text=self.title)
        self.button.pack()

    def delete(self):
        global removable_widget_dict
        self.button.destroy()
        del removable_widget_dict[self.key]
        print(removable_widget_dict)


for i in range(10):
    key = f'item{i}'
    removable_widget_dict[key] = RemovableWidget(f'Button {i}', root, key)
print(removable_widget_dict)

for key in removable_widget_dict.keys():
    if key == 'item5':
        removable_widget_dict[key].delete()
        break

root.mainloop()
```

in simple terms: there is the class that will be the removable widgets, each time an instance of that class is created in the for loop, it is saved in dictionary. when deleting You match Your criteria with dictionary key and execute a function to delete the widget and remove it from the dictionary